# Knockout Bindings what is required in this function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

***EDIT***

So as it stands, this method doesn't actually work as expected.

This issue was due to my `changeUrl` method, I fixed it and now this "does work". I have it in quotes because, I'm not sure what is and isn't needed to have a proper working binding.

---

Here is the binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatUrl = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var data = valueAccessor();

        var href = appStrap.changeUrl(ko.unwrap(data.url), ko.unwrap(data.id), data.replace);

        $(element).attr("href", href);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { attr: { href:  href } }, context);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = valueAccessor();

        var href = appStrap.changeUrl(ko.unwrap(data.url), ko.unwrap(data.id), data.replace);

        $(element).attr("href", href);
    }
};
```

Here is it's usage:

```
<tr>
<td><a data-bind="formatUrl: { url: $root.GenericUrl, id: id, replace: '\\[ID\\]' }">Details</a>
</tr>
```

So generic url is something like this:

```
http://www.somehost.com/SomeController/SomeAction/[ID]
```

And the url will need to look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.somehost.com/SomeController/SomeAction/9fedb631-67ec-484c-9a7d-5f6bf62fb733"></a>
```

What do I need, and what shouldn't been in my binding handler. For example, should `ko.applyBindingsToNode` be there? is it currently being used incorrectly? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking us to review your bindingHandler? If so, you may want to check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, i suppose it is reviewing the code, but also its a question of whether I have used the code correctly! It is meant for here, there is nothing conceptual going on.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to just call back into the original binding handlers rather than using ko.applyBindingsToNode and controlsDescendantBindings: true

So something like this would be my suggestion:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.formatUrl = {
    changeUrl: function(data) {
          return appStrap.changeUrl(ko.unwrap(data.url), ko.unwrap(data.id), data.replace);
    },
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

        var href = ko.bindingHandlers.formatUrl.changeUrl(valueAccessor());

        valueAccessor = function(){
            return { href: href };  
        }

        return ko.bindingHandlers.attr.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

        var href = ko.bindingHandlers.formatUrl.changeUrl(valueAccessor());

        valueAccessor = function(){
            return { href: href };  
        }

        return ko.bindingHandlers.attr.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this in a binding handler. You can just use [the `attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html): the docs even use `href` as a typical example. In addition, View Model logic is more easily unit tested.

For example:

```js
var Item = function(urlProvider, id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.url = ko.computed(function() {
        return urlProvider.GenericUrl.replace("[ID]", self.id());
    });
};

var RootViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.GenericUrl = "http://test/controller/action/[ID]";
    self.Item = new Item(self, 42, "Something something");
};

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table data-bind="with: Item">
    <tr>
        <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: url }">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice.... I like it, but i don't want to do that. Its too intrusive in the model. However, from what I can determine you don't need a binding handler you can run an inline function. But then its either, handler or inline function, and handler is more reusable.